# how to optimally use nifi wait processor

Tags: apache-nifi

I am currently creating a flow, where I will be merging result of 10K http response. I have couple of questions. (please refer image below, I am numbering my questions as per image).

1) As queue is becoming too long, is it ok to put "concurrent task" as 10 for invokeHTTP? what should drive this? # of cores on the server?

2) wait is showing quite a big number, is this just # of bytes it is writing? or is this using that much memory? if this is just a write, then I might be ok...but if it is some internal queue, then soon I may run out of memory?
does it make sense to reduce this number? by increasing "Run Schedule" from 0 to say 20 sec?

3) what exactly is "Back Pressure Data Size Threshold", value is set at 1 GB, does it meant, if size of ff in queue is more than that, nifi will start dropping it? or will it somehow stop processing of upstream processor?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Yes increasing concurrent tasks on InvokeHttp would probably make sense. I wouldn't jump right to 10, but would test increasing from 1 to 2, 2 to 3, etc until it seems to be working better. Concurrent tasks is the number of threads that can concurrently execute the processor, the total number of threads for your NiFi instance is defined in the controller settings from top right menu under Timer Driven threads, you should set the timer driven threads based of the # of CPUs/core you have.

2) The stats on the processor are totals for the last 5 mins, so "In" is the total size of all the flow files that have come in to the processor in the last 5 mins. You can see "Out" is almost the same # which means almost all the flow files in have also been transferred out.

3) Back-pressure stops the upstream processor from executing until the back pressure threshold is reduced. The data size threshold is saying "when the total size of all flow files in the queue exceeds 1GB, then stop executing the upstream processor so that no more data enters the queue while the downstream processor works on the queue". In the case of a self-loop connection, I think back-pressure won't stop the processor from executing otherwise it will end up in a dead-lock where it can't produce more data but also can't work off the queue. In any case, data is never dropped unless you set flow file expiration on the queue.